# Properly close Pop-up by clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

i have some bug in my **html+css+js** documents. here is the map, and if u click on one of these numbers, there is a pop-up (info tag), but it lags if u clicking outside of it. It works only if u click **"location_pop"** div, but i want to close pop up by simply clicking outside of it. I need to write it only using singe html doc to put it into *T123 Tilda Block*.

[html doc](https://pastebin.com/Ldg1BSR1)
open this document to fully see a picture

i have added click event, but probably have some bug in vars i dont know but its not working.

[js code](https://pastebin.com/B1VMJUbF)

```
        document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if(e.target === popupBg) {
                popupBg.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like only clicking the `popupBg` causes it to close. It might help to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just seen your bug, you are comparing the wrong element.If the user click any where in svg the popup will close.
Instead try this

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.tagName === 'svg') {
            popupBg.classList.remove('active');
        }
});
```

Comment: it helps so much you are awesome my friend!

Comment: Ye may u please help if u know how can i do logical disunction **_OR_** if it is not **_svg_** block but something outside the map box? if u wish i can create another stckoverflow question thread or maybe u can give short answer here, in comments ? gracias, thank u, спасибо

Comment: @EgorMarkin glad to help you, simply remove the if condition for that